# login automatically internet explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I have a program in a server and the user access to it by the ip address https://123.45.54.63

Then the server ask for credentials and users can mark on remember my credentials to autofill de user and password fields the next time.

But i do not know how to make the automatize the login so the user does not have to click on login and just use the application by accessing to the server ip.

I mark in Tools  -> Internet options -> security -> local intranet -> customize -> and mark the login automatically option for intranet but it still ask for the credentials autofilled.

It is possible to make internet explorer 11 to log automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Whether the user's computer and the server is in the same Intranet Zone?

If they are in the same zone, you could try to select the "Automatic logon with current user name and password" option (Internet options -> security -> local intranet -> customize ).

If still not working, you could try to add the IP address to the "Local Intranet Sites" in security in IE.

If the user's computer and the server are not in the same zone, you should enable the "Automatic logon with current user name and password" in the Internet Zone.

**Edit:**

Please check [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password),

When using the **Windows Integrated authentication**, the Internet Explorer might automatically authenticate a user's logon and password and maintain security. You could check the conditions for Internet Explorer to automatically authenticate a user's logon and password and maintain security:

- *Windows Integrated authentication, also known as Windows NT
  Challenge/Response, must be enabled in the Web site properties in
  IIS. Anonymous authentication is attempted first, followed by Windows
  Integrated authentication, Digest authentication (if applicable), and
  finally Basic (clear text) authentication.*
- *Both the client and the Web server must be either in the same Microsoft Windows NT-based or Microsoft Windows 2000-based domain or in trusted Windows NT-based or
  Windows 2000-based domains in which the user's account can be granted
  permissions to resources on the IIS-based computer.*
- *The user's browser must be Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer is the only
  browser that supports Windows Integrated authentication (NTCR).*
- *Internet Explorer must consider the requested URL to be on the
  intranet (local). If the computer name portion of the requested URL
  contains periods (such as http://www.microsoft.com and
  http://10.0.0.1), Internet Explorer assumes that the requested
  address exists on the Internet and does not pass any credentials
  automatically. Addresses without periods (such as http://webserver)
  are considered to be on the intranet (local); Internet Explorer
  passes credentials automatically. The only exception is addresses
  included in the Intranet zone in Internet Explorer. Internet
  Explorer's Intranet zone security setting must be set to Automatic
  logon only in Intranet zone. This is the default setting for Internet
  Explorer. For additional information about Internet Explorer security
  zones, click the article number below to view the article in the
  Microsoft Knowledge Base:*
- *The user requesting the Web page must have appropriate file system (NTFS)
  permissions to the Web page as well as all of the objects referenced
  in the Web page. For example, a user may have Full Control rights to
  a Web page, but is prompted for a password if the Web page refers to
  graphics that are in a secure folder.*

When using the **Basic (clear text) authentication or Digest authentication**. Internet Explorer does not pass your user name and password automatically when you are using Basic (clear text) authentication or Digest authentication. Therefore, you are always prompted for credentials when you are using these authentication methods.

Comment: Hello thank you for answer but it does not work, when i apply all changes and trying to access again it ask for the credentials despite they appeared auto filled.

Comment: @Adriiboom please check the edit in the above reply, When using the Windows Integrated authentication, the Internet Explorer might automatically authenticate a user's logon and password and maintain security. You could check the conditions for Internet Explorer to automatically authenticate a user's logon and password and maintain security.